# Make js closures execute right away

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can see an issue in the following code:

```
var elems = {
    'elem1': 'param1fds',
    'elem2': 'paramaafds2',
    'elem3': 'paramfdsfd3fdsfds'
  };

for (var k in elems) {
  $('#' + k).click(function(e) {
  // k is always elem3 when I click on the element
  // elems[k] == 'paramfdsfd3fdsfds'
```

By the time the code is getting executed, `k` is equal `elem3`. How can I deal with that?

Comment: As the code uses jQuery, I've added the tag to your question. If you feels it denatures it, fee free to remove it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript closure inside loops – simple practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The standard generic solution is to add an [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/) protecting your variable in a closure:

```
for (var k in elems) {
   (function(k){
     $('#' + k).click(function(e) {
        // k is always elem3 when I click on the
     })
    })(k);
}
```

As you're using jQuery, you could also use `$.each`:

```
$.each(elems, function(k){
     $('#' + k).click(function(e) {
```

And a third solution would be to use `on` and provide the `data`:

```
for (var k in elems) {
    $('#' + k).on('click', {k:k}, function(e) {  
         // use e.data.k here
```

In the near future, with ES6, a fourth solution will be block scoped variables using [`let`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let):

```
for (let k in elems) {
   $('#' + k).click(function(e) {
      // k is OK
```

Comment: thats called a self-executing function.

Comment: The important point is to wrap a new function around the variable. JavaScript is scoped with functions, so the new function's variable captures the value of the variable when the loop is run.

Comment: what's this behaviour called in js?

Comment: What behavior ? Your problem is due to asynchronicity (or rather the k variable being "free") and you fix it by creating a new "scope" protecting your variable (in JS the scope of a non global variable is the function call, and functions declared in a scope recursively access variables in the scope).

Comment: The concept that you might want to dive into is called "scope" (and I just thought about a new fourth solution...).

Comment: @dystroy is the 4th solution the one I just posted?

Comment: @Mathletics no, see edit, my fourth solution is ES6 based. Your solution is too verbose to my taste to enter my list, especially when OP uses jQuery, I don't like the idea of creating an array just for iterating properties. But of course it also works, no problem.

Comment: @dystroy hmm, to each their own.

Answer (score 1):

```
var elems = {
    'elem1': 'param1fds',
    'elem2': 'paramaafds2',
    'elem3': 'paramfdsfd3fdsfds'
  };

for (var k in elems) {
    (function(elem){
        $('#' + elem).click(function(e) {});
    })(k);
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd argue that the modern solution to this is to do it functionally, rather than with a loop:

```
Object.keys(elems).forEach( function(elKey) {
    $('#' + elems[elKey]).click(function(e) {});
});
```

It's the same result as using an IIFE but is, I think, a little easier to follow.